# What is the simplest way to implement an Entity Framework 6 Add-or-Update method

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a project that uses Entity Framework 6 that does an Add-or-Update (i.e. Upsert) for a bunch of different entity types.  For each of these entities, there is an surrogate integer ID (i.e. primary key), a natural key (e.g. customer ID) used for external lookups, and a set of descriptive fields (e.g. Name, Description, etc.)

I have an AddOrUpdate method that does a lookup of the natural key, finds an existing entity in the database, and updates the entity with the new values (if it exists) or creates a new entity and adds it to the database (if it does not already exist).

Here is a sample of the method I came up with (note that "key" is the natural key, not the surrogate ID):

```
public void AddOrUpdate(int key, string name)
{
    var customer = _database.Customers
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == key);

    var exists = customer != null;

    if (!exists)
        customer = new Customer();

    customer.Name = name;
    // Update other descriptive fields here

    if (!exists)
        _database.Customers.Add(customer);

    _database.Save();
}
```

The code works correctly, but it always feels a bit messy. I'm interested in knowing if someone has a better way of solving this problem with Entity Framework that is structurally simpler, reads better, or can be done in less lines of code (without sacrificing readability), and is still easy to unit test.

If so, please post your refactoring of the code above, so that I can learn from your example.

Comment: It seems this would be better on [codereview.se] since it's working code.

Comment: To be honest, this is the first I've heard of Code Review.  I'll take a look at it and see if it would make more sense to migrate my question over there instead.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EntityFramework already implements this for you, [you can learn more about it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbsetmigrationsextensions.addorupdate%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
void Main()
{
    using (AppContext context = new AppContext())
    {
        context.Users.AddOrUpdate(...);
    }
}

public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    
    
}

public class User 
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

## EDIT

This answer has been down voted twice because apparently it's not thread safe. This may be a surprise to a few but Entity Framework, as a framework, isn't thread safe.

[MSDN DbContext - Thread Safety](http://MSDN%20DbContext%20Class%20-%20Thread%20Safety)

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
> thread safe. ***Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.***

Basically, the thread safety of my solution is irrelevant as any use of Entity Frameworks DbContext (in particular SaveChanges / SaveChangesAsync methods) across parallel threads is going to give you issues as is, out of the box.

Comment: This is definitely a simpler, cleaner, and easier to test solution than what I implemented.  I'm surprised that I've never noticed this extension method before today.  I'll give it a try today and see if I run into any issues.  If not, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.  Thanks for this suggestion!

Comment: Can that method be used outside of Migrations? It bothers me a bit that it isn't in the main part of EF.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Reflecting into the implementation, I can't see anything that would prevent you from using it outside of Migrations, and should work with anything deriving from `IDbSet`. Keep in mind, however, that I haven't tested it so I could be wrong.

Comment: Other threads on this topic warn that AddOrUpdate is not thread safe. Multiple threads with different contexts will duplicate records.

Comment: Also, does this handle in bulk properly yet or is it still a round trip for every record?

Comment: Every record is a round trip, if using entity framework, but there are plugins for bulk update, look on nuget

Comment: It doesn't work on anything that implements `IDbSet` unless the class itself has an `AddOrUpdate` method. -- So, if you have your own `IDbSet` implementation (say for unit tests), you have still have to manually implement it. -- Any advice on the implementation?

Comment: -1 As @Sentinel has pointed out, this method is not thread safe. This means that you should not use it except during migrations.

Comment: @Ergwun, No it doesn't mean that, if that was true we wouldn't use DbContext (it's not thread safe), it means you need to be aware in multithreaded applications that it's not thread safe to avoid concurrency issues. There's hardly ever a reason for me to be implementing multithreading in a web app, if something needs to be processed in parallel like that I'll ship it into a queue for it to be processed by a service designed for that. If you need it to be Async, you can use AddOrUpdateAsync. As long as two threads aren't attempting to access the same resource at the same time, no issues.

Comment: @AydinAdn Fair enough - I didn't put that very well. What I was trying to get at is that `AddOrUpdate` will most likely not play nicely with whichever concurrency pattern you are using to handle conflicting updates. If you are using it in a web application you need to be aware that requests can be handled concurrently, and be sure that `AddOrUpdate`'s "client wins" conflict resolution behaviour is what you actually want. If the use case is outside of typical multi-threaded web request handling, then it may meet an application's needs, but it is worth adding this caveat.